# Cannot Delete or Edit drawn boxes in leaflet

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

I am currently using angular with ui-leaflet.  When I attempt to delete a drawn rectangle, the "finger" icon that usually appears does not.  This is also true for the edit function.  In the case of the edit function, the dotted lines appear but clicking on them does nothing.  In both cases the usual edit boxes that appear are absent.  An example of its proper functionality can be found [here](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/examples/full.html).  I would post my code if I could, but any help would be appreciated.  Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the wrapper (ui-leaflet) it was with leaflet.  I was not importing the css file into my project and the bounding boxes were not being displayed.